# Convert columns on pandas from non-null object to float

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some difficulties to convert the values from object to float!!!

I saw some examples but I couldn't be able to get it.

I would like to have a for loop to convert the values in all columns.

I didn't have yet a script cause I saw different ways to do it

```
Terawatt-hours  Total Asia Pacific  Total CIS   Total Europe
2000             0.428429            0             0.134473
2001             0.608465            0             0.170166
2002             0.829254            0             0.276783
2003             1.11654             0             0.468726
2004             1.46406             0             0.751126
2005             1.85281             0             1.48641
2006             2.29128             0             2.52412
2007             2.74858             0             3.81573
2008             3.3306              0             7.5011
2009             4.3835              7.375e-06     14.1928
2010             6.73875             0.000240125   23.2634
2011             12.1544             0.00182275    46.7135
```

I tried this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'bp-stats-review-2019-all-data.xls')
columns = list(df.head(0))
for i in range(len(columns)):
    df[columns[i]].astype(float)
```

Comment: which column are trying to convert? and post the data as text

Comment: @komatiraju032, I'd like to convert all the columns and I already change the data, sorry for the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear as to which column you are trying to convert, So I am sharing the example for the 1st column in your screenshot.

```
df['Terawatt-hours'] = df.Terawatt-hours.astype(float)
```

or same for any other column.

**EDIT**

for creating a loop on the dataframe and change it for all the columns, you can do the following :

Generating a dummy dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(20, 4)), columns=list('abcd'))
```

Check the type of column in dataframe :

```
for column in df.columns:
    print(df[column].dtype)
```

Change the type of all the columns to float

```
for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = df[column].astype(float)
```

Comment: If the question is not clear to you, better option is to wait for the clarification by OP rather than posting partially working answers.

Comment: Hello, sorry for my lack of information. I'd like to convert all the columns and I already change the data, sorry for the issue. Is it possible using a for loop?

Comment: @TayzerDamasceno You are still unclear, what do you need the loop for ?

Comment: @TayzerDamasceno I have edited my answer, let me know if this is not what you need.

Comment: @dped, sorry again if I was unclear but it is what I'm looking for. Basically to convert the values in each column from objects to float. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear? which columns are you trying to convert to float and also post what you have done.

EDIT:

what you tried is right until the last line of your code where you failed to reassign the columns.
    `df[columns[i]] = df[columns[i]].astype(float)`

also try using `df.columns` to get column names instead of `list(df.head(0))`

the link [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to pandas docs on how to cast a pandas object to a specified dtype

Comment: Hello, sorry for my lack of information. I'd like to convert all the columns and I already change the data, sorry for the issue. Is it possible using a for loop?